# newData() used with deletes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been experimenting with the following security rule, which works ok at first but gets stuck when I try to delete data.  I started with scenario 1, which allowed me to create a new entry but doesn't allow me to delete an entry.  This makes sense as newData() refers to the entry after the write action, so the value for "blocker" no longer exists.
*Scenario 1:*

```
".write": "auth != null && !root.child('suspensions').child(newData.child('blocker').val()).hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

I then tried a second scenario where both data() and newData() are options.  In this case, even the initial writes of new data are being blocked.
*Scenario 2*

```
".write": "auth != null && (!root.child('suspensions').child(data.child('blocker').val()).hasChild(auth.uid) || !root.child('suspensions').child(newData.child('blocker').val()).hasChild(auth.uid))"
```

I've also tried to place the individual clauses within their own brackets `((!...) || (!...))`, but this doesn't help.  So a couple of questions emerge.  Why does the extra clause using data() block a write of new data when I'm using OR?  Am I using a sound approach for deletes, by using both data() and newData()?  Any suggestions are welcome.